# Way to set focus manually (e.g. right click -> set focus) to an element on a website?

Tags: javascript, plugins, google-chrome-extension, focus

I'm working a lot with [NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/) to test website accessibility.

One way to move through a website is to use the tab key. So to reach an area that I want to test, I often have to press the tab key until I reach the needed area. This sometimes is very cumbersome and means repeating the tab key again and again after page refreshes.

It would be very nice to somehow set the focus manually, e.g. by right clicking on a link and choose "Set focus" or something like that. It would be even greater to have an extension which automatically sets focus to a specified element after each page refresh, so when developing, the focus is always on the right element after a page refresh.

Is there any browser extension (Chrome/Firefox) for this? I found some extensions that allow to inject custom JS/CSS ([Control Freak](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/control-freak/jgnchehlaggacipokckdlbdemfeohdhc), [JScript tricks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jscript-tricks/odialddippdmebbfbflcneemfdglimod), [Script Runner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptrunner/nilfinipmkbgemlbmohlildijohlniho/related) for Chrome) which can be used for something like this, but it's still a bit of a hassle.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing tool (then the question is off-topic) or are you looking to write such a tool (then the question is too broad unless you have more concrete questions)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using browser cache to save the last field accesed and then you can focus the concrecte input with something like

```
$(selector).focus(); //for example with jQuery.
```

Store/Retrive data from browser cache:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a tool that can automatically do all of this, by telling it which element it should focus after a page reload.